# Undefined reference to 'pthread_create' — linker command option order (libraries before/after object files?)

Tags: c, ubuntu, linker, pthreads

When I try to compile that, I receive a particular error. But, it's not possible because I use the right flag. In `server.c` there is the library `pthread.h`.
So, how can I resolve my linking problem?
I'm using Linux (Ubuntu).

```
make
gcc -c -Wall -Wunused -ansi -pedantic -ggdb  -o Server1.o Server.c
gcc -c -Wall -Wunused -ansi -pedantic -ggdb  Util.c
gcc -o Server1.exe -Wall -Wunused -ansi -pedantic -ggdb -lpthread -lm Server1.o Util.o
Server1.o: In function `main':
/home/ruggero/ruggero_fine/Server.c:1002: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Server1.exe] Errore 1
```

Comment: Did you try -pthread (without 'l')? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662909/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create-in-linux-c-programming

Comment: The `header` is `pthread.h`; that is not the library, though.  The library would have a name such as `libpthread.so` (at link time; and a name such as `libpthread.so.1` at runtime).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### List libraries after the object files

When linking only object files and libraries, list the libraries after the object files:

```
gcc -o Server1.exe -Wall -Wunused -ansi -pedantic -ggdb  Server1.o Util.o -lpthread -lm
```

When the linking command includes source files, list the source files and object files (if any) before the libaries.  The `-l` options come at the end of the command line, therefore.  Relevant `-L` options specifying where a library is found should come before the `-l` option specifying the library.

The subsidiary question is:

> Why does it work?

When the C compiler invokes the linker, it tells the linker to pull in some system object files with names like `crt0.o`, and tells it to look for a symbol `main` (or possibly `_main()`, depending on local naming conventions).  It also supplies the object files and libraries in the order you specified on the command line.  When it comes across an object file, the linker notes the definitions it provides, and the unsatisfied references it makes.  When it comes across a library, it scans the library to see whether it can satisfy any unsatisfied references.  If the library can supply any as yet unsatisfied references, then it includes (the relevant parts of) the library 'in the executable'.  For a shared library, the linker ensures that the library will be loaded at runtime.  For a static library, the linker includes the object files from the library that satisfy at least one reference, rescanning until there are no further references that can be satisfied.  If the library satisfies no references, it is ignored.  When the process is complete, if any references are still unsatisfied, you get the error messages.

So, in your scenario, you had `-lpthread` before either `Server1.o` or `Util.o`.  Since `-lpthread` does not provide a `main` function and that was the only relevant unsatisfied symbol, it was ignored.  The mathematics library, `-lm` may also have been ignored, or it may be an empty stub to keep code devised for other systems where the mathematics library is separate from the main C library.  Then the linker read your object files, and found the reference to `pthread_create()`.  When it scanned the C library `-lc` (`libc.so`) afterwards, it found symbols to satisfy everything except `pthread_create`.

When the libraries are listed after the object files, then the linker knew it needed `pthread_create` when it scanned `-lpthread` and ensured that the shared library would be loaded at runtime.

#### GNU `ld` and the `--as-needed` option

The discussion above is essentially platform-neutral.  If you follow the 'libraries after object files' rule, your linker line has the maximum chance of working correctly on all platforms.

If you are on a system using the GNU `binutils` package, and the GNU `ld` command in particular, you may find different behaviour.

The manual from [Sourceware](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) (which is where you are redirected if you try http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/manuals) includes the information:

> `--as-needed`
>   `--no-as-needed`
>   This option affects ELF DT_NEEDED tags for dynamic libraries mentioned on the command line after the `--as-needed` option. Normally the linker will add a DT_NEEDED tag for each dynamic library mentioned on the command line, regardless of whether the library is actually needed or not. `--as-needed` causes a DT_NEEDED tag to only be emitted for a library that at that point in the link satisfies a non-weak undefined symbol reference from a regular object file or, if the library is not found in the DT_NEEDED lists of other libraries, a non-weak undefined symbol reference from another dynamic library. Object files or libraries appearing on the command line after the library in question do not affect whether the library is seen as needed. This is similar to the rules for extraction of object files from archives. `--no-as-needed` restores the default behaviour.

It appears that different versions of different systems use different values for the `as-needed` option.  While the `--no-as-needed` behaviour is convenient in that it lets you order libraries and object files in more or less any order on your command line, it also means that all the libraries listed on the command line are loaded at run time, even if there are no symbols actually used from the library (thus `--no-as-needed` is equivalent to a hypothetical `--whether-needed-or-not` flag). Using the `--as-needed` option is the classic and portable behaviour.

Rumour has it that some Linux distributions changed the default behaviour on their systems from `--no-as-needed` to `--as-needed` sometime in the last 5 years or so (the first half of the second decade of the third millennium, for sake of argument).  You can find evidence in support of this rumour in a number of questions on SO.

Comment: right, it works. can you explain me why?

Comment: I always thought that gcc parsed from right to left, and hence the libraries need to be listed at the end, to ensure that they are loaded first.

Comment: @Neo: I've never heard of a linker doing that.  That's not quite the same as "there is no linker that does that", but in all the time I've been working on Unix systems, all the Unix systems I've worked on have had linkers that worked from left to right through the argument list.  Granted, that's only a little over 25 years experience, and only a dozen and more variants of Unix (Zeus, anyone?), but I've never heard of a contrarian system such as you describe.  And, specifically, none of the GCC systems I currently work with (MacOS X, Linux, HP-UX, AIX, Solaris, Cygwin) works right-to-left.

Comment: Ahhh! Maybe it was something I misinterpreted/misunderstood. And err.. if my comment sounded like I was trying to say you were wrong or something, that was NOT my intention. :) And 25 years! WoooOOoooW!

Comment: Wonderful answer. I'm just curious, is this behavior documented? At least for gcc?

Comment: The behaviour of the GNU `ld` command is described in the manual; it is part of `binutils`.  The section on [Options](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/ld/Options.html#Options) includes a discussion of argument order in general terms, outlining many of the points I made.

Comment: Everything described here is valid only when `--as-needed` option is used, which is default in Ubuntu but not in vanilla GNU ld (or when libraries are static, which is not the case here). I don't think the linked ld manual describes anything like this for shared libs (only for static ones), because it's not the default behavior.

Comment: @wRAR: the sequence of arguments described here (object files before libraries) will work with all loaders, regardless of options such as `--as-needed`, and regardless of whether it is GNU `ld` or some other loader.  You may also get away with various other sequences on various platforms subject to various conditions, but the order described (object files, then libraries) works.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't say it won't. I'm just saying the answer describes behavior which is not true for all platforms, and specifically wrong for the linker described here (GNU ld) on most implementations of the platform described here (Linux), without mentioning its range of applicability.

Answer (score 3):

Use -pthread when compiling. Try it and you will solve your problem