# How compile with <minix/mthread.h> in Minix?

Tags: c, pthreads, clang, minix

Currently, I am studying Minix and I am doing a system based on *threads* and do not know how to compile my program.

For example:
    `Mthreads.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <minix/mthread.h>

void hola(int y){
     printf("Hola Mundo");
}

int main(){

    mthread_thread_t a;

    mthread_create(&a, NULL, (void*)hola, 0);
    mthread_join(a, NULL);
}
```

Then I run clang to compile:

```
# clang Mthreads.c 
/var/tmp/g-10649b.o: In function `main':
Mthreads.c:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `mthread_create'
Mthreads.c:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `mthread_join'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: I never used minix however I can give you a hint: the error that you're getting is a linker error. The compiler was able to find the symbols "mthread_create" and "mthread_join" inside the header file: "minix/mthread.h" however it cannot find the implementation of these functions. Usually these will be in a c library (either static or dynamic). So you need to figure out where the minix libraries are and tell the linker to look for them with "-l<libname>" option in command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to 'pthread\_create' — linker command option order (libraries before/after object files?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253200/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create-linker-command-option-order-libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **mthread** library when compiling. Try it and you will solve your problem

```
clang Mthreads.c -lmthread
```

Comment: Do you mean `-pthread` as in the text or `-lpthread` as in the command line?  Also, why `pthread` (which normally means POSIX threads) rather than `-lmthread` (which looks more natural to an outsider's eyes) or perhaps `-lthread`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: you guessed correctly, it should really be `-lmthread` in MINIX.