# Undefined reference to pthread_create

Tags: c, pthreads

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* cuoco(void* arg)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Inizio codice cuoco\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"Fine codice cuoco\n");
    return NULL;
}

void* cameriere(void* arg)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Inizio codice cameriere\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"Fine codice cameriere\n");
    return NULL;
}

void* cliente(void* arg)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Inizio codice cliente\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"Fine codice cliente\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void* (*routine)(void*);
    routine=cuoco;
    pthread_t thread_cuoco,thread_cameriere,thread_cliente;
    pthread_create(&thread_cuoco,NULL,routine,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

And in the compiler options I insert *-lpthread*
But it says:
"Undefined reference to pthread_create"
I use ubuntu 10.10, so I already have pthread library installed, I can't figure the reason of this error.

Comment: Show us how you compile your program.

Comment: How did you add the linker option & where? Which version of Code::Blocks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to pthread\_create in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662909/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create-in-linux)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use -lpthread as the last compiler flag.

example: 
`gcc -o sample sample.c -lpthread`

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri No you don't. You probably botched the codeblocks settings. +1 to counter wrong downvote.

Comment: Yes, I have put it.It's on settings->compiler and debugger->(compiler settings tab)->other options.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: That is not right. It is more of a linker setting. So do this: settings->compiler and debugger->linker settings (tab). Select "Add" under Link libraries section. Add the path to pthread library (most likely /usr/lib/libpthread.so). Try building then

Comment: Plus you should not downvote if you tried it, but it didn't work, but you didn't tell it us either...

Comment: Note that the use of `-pthread` is preferable, because `-lpthread` will fail to link on a system with only `libpthread.a` installed.

Answer (score 15):

Without seeing the compiler command, I suspect `-lpthread` is not at end. Libraries need to be placed at end of the compiler command:

> gcc main.c -lpthread

However, use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`, as `-pthread` may add other settings (like defining the macro `_REENTRANT` for example).

Comment: I compile it with code::blocks, in the C::B options now I changed _-lpthread_ with _-pthread_, but nothing has changed.
This is the only options I have in settings.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with code::blocks, but can you attempt a complete rebuild of the source?

Answer (score 5):

Use the following command:

`gcc -pthread -o main main.c`

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, you should add string pthread.

`Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC Linker -> Libraries -> Libraries (-l) -> Add -> pthread`

After this, you can Build your project.

Comment: But the OP said in a comment that he is using Code::Blocks, not Eclipse.

Answer (score -2):

found the solution guys :D
just go to `settings >> compiler >> linker tab >>add lib`

go to drive and go to lib folder and find `x86_64_linux_gnu` and find `pthread`
enjoy :)