# Fixing pthread_create reference error on WSL

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a C program that I have been working on across multiple machines, and although it compiles correctly on my MacBook, I cannot get the program to compile on the Windows Subsystem for Linux, running Ubuntu 18.04 and using gcc.

The program spawns multiple threads, and when I try to compile it on the Windows Subsystem I get the error `` undefined reference to `pthread_create ``.

Several other questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803145/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create/37238361#37238361), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264984/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651274/pthread-create-return-error-on-compiling), suggest using `-lpthread` as a compiler flag to solve the issue, but I am already doing this and it compiles fine on OSX, so I suspect the issue might be related to my WSL configuration.

My Makefile is:

```
CC = gcc
CCOPTS = -Wall -c -g -ggdb
LINKOPTS = -Wall -g -ggdb -lpthread

all: calc

calc: calc.o smp3_tests.o testrunner.o
    $(CC) $(LINKOPTS) -o $@ $^

calc.o: calc.c calc.h
    $(CC) $(CCOPTS) -o $@ $<
```

I am including the pthread header with `#include <pthread.h>` and calling the `pthread_create` function with `pthread_create(&multiplierThread, NULL, multiplier, arg)`.

Does anyone know what could be causing this compiler error?

Comment: I don’t know anything about WSL but unless it’s using a different convention from the GNU toolchain, don’t use `CCOPTS` and `LINKOPTS`, use the conventional variable names (i.e. `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`). If for no other reason then because it makes explicitly writing the other rules redundant.

Comment: Closely related: [Difference between -pthread and -lpthread while compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23250863/2402272).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overall, with GCC you ought to be using the `-pthread` option for both compiling your sources and linking your objects.  You do not then need (nor really want) to include `-lpthead` explicitly among your link libraries:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -c -g -ggdb -pthread
LDFLAGS= -Wall -g -ggdb -pthread

calc: calc.o smp3_tests.o testrunner.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

calc.o: calc.c calc.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

If you *do* link `-lpthread` explicitly, however, then the order in which object files and `-l` options appear in the link command is significant to many linkers.  If given at all, then the `-lpthread` option should appear at the end of the link command, after all object files that call functions it is expected to provide.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer! This solution solved my problem