# -lpthread linking error

Tags: c, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [undefined reference to pthread_create in linux (c programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662909/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create-in-linux-c-programming)

There is the following program:

```
void *thread(void *vargp);

int main() {
  pthread_t tid;

  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread, NULL);
  exit(0);
}

/* thread routine */
void *thread(void *vargp) {
  sleep(1);
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return NULL;
}
```

I am supposed to correct it. I allready added the includes left:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

But I still get the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccHwCS8c.o: In function `main':
1.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: ld returned output state 1
```

I tried adding -lpthread with the compiler like the answers sayd but I still get this error codes:

```
@lap:~$ gcc -Wall -lpthread 1.c -o uno

/tmp/ccl19SMr.o: In function `main':
1.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: ld returned exit state 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile it with `-lpthread` flag in order to link the `libpthread` to your executable.

Also you should to add the [pthread_join()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) function in order to let your main thread to wait for the new thread ending. In your current code you will  not see the `Hello World`because main thread ending will cause all son threads exiting.

Comment: You are right I dont see `Hello World` at all. I will add pthread_join() but I dont know what arguments to add.

Comment: @Rkan Please follow the link: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html

Answer (score 3):

In your compilation/linking add "-lpthread".

Comment: I tried with `gcc -Wall -pthread uno.c -o uno` still not working

Comment: @Rkan: It's `-lpthread`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly mention the `-pthread` option while compiling.
Without this linker is not able to find the reference of pthread library.
Do like this :

`gcc -Wall -pthread test.c -o test.out`