# which type of lock mechanism to use in shared library ie accessed by posix threads

Tags: c, multithreading, locks

I have an application using posix threads ie using a static library which has some global variables and I dont have any thread implementation in libray.
Somebody told me you should use pthread_mutex if you are using pthreads in that file else simple mutex.

As library is thread free so which lock (specially mutex) to use in library to protect globals.

I tried linux/kernel/mutex.h ie obviously bad to use kernel's object to use in user space and compiler too warning.
So where will I get this simple mutex!!!

Comment: If you are referring to pthread_mutex_t you 'll find them in pthread.h.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

you can compile this with: `gcc -o mutex program.c -pthread -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (note not -lpthread for an explanation see the answer of EmployedRussian in this thread: [Undefined reference to pthread_create in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662909/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create-in-linux-c-programming))

If you get this to compile you are there