# No input files or undefined reference when compiling C on Ubuntu

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker, pthreads

i am trying to compile this code in C. I am using

```
 gcc -o -pthread test1.c
```

I am using Linux. Unfortunately I get:

```
undefined reference to `pthread_create'
 undefined reference to `thread_join'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I try to compile:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>


    void* thread_func(void* parameter){

        int i =0;
        for(i=0; i<5;i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }

      return 0;


    }


 int main (int argc, char *argv)
 {
     pthread_t thread_handle;
     int ret = pthread_create(&thread_handle,0,thread_func,0);
     if(ret != 0) {
        printf("Create thread failed! error: %d",ret);
        return 1;
      }

      thread_join(thread_handle,0);

      return 0;

}
```

When I use the second solution from here: [Undefined reference to pthread_create in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662909/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create-in-linux)

I get another error. I am in the directory where my test1.c .

```
no input files





ADDIN ERRORS:
1)using gcc -o someFile -pthread test1.c
-undefined reference to `thread_join'
2)gcc -o -pthread test1.c
-undefined reference to `thread_join'
-undefined reference to `pthread_create'

3)gcc test1.c -o test1.o -I. -lpthread 
- undefined reference to `thread_join'
4)gcc -pthread -o test.c
- no input files
```

I would be grateful for help because I can't learn threads because I can't compile it.

Comment: i just want to compile and run test.c How to do it then?

Answer (score 1):

Word after option `-o` is the output file, i.e. you specified `-pthread` to be the output file. Change to `gcc -o someFile -pthread test1.c` should do the trick. Your executable output file would then be `someFile`.

Comment: `gcc -o someFile` (without the `-`, `someFile` being your output file name)

Comment: To run the output you would run `someFile`.

Comment: @SzymonSutek: Could you add to your question the other commands that you have tried and what error they have produced?

Comment: OK missed it first time. So in addition to the main answer above, you need `pthread_join` in your .c source, not `thread_join`. All pthread calls start with a `p`.

Answer (score 0):

try compiling with -lpthread

```
gcc -lpthread test1.c -o test1
```

Comment: @SzymonSutek: What error exactly does this produce?

Answer (score 0):

The linker takes things in the order written on the command line.

So, in your example, when the linker gets to your .o file, and needs to find the external reference for the pthread calls, it has nothing to look in.

You could try:

```
gcc test1.c -o test1.o -I. -lpthread
```

The `-I.` says to look for `#include "header.h"` files in the current directory the `-lpthread` says to use the `libpthread.a` library file.

Comment: `-lpthread` is bad advice. Always use `-pthread` unless you know _exactly_ what you're doing. `-pthread` is not only a linker flag, it's a compiler flag too.

Comment: also `gcc` without `-c` compiles to executable, not to object file.