# Link library correct with ROS and cmake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, pthreads, ros

I'm trying to add use some code for a MOXA I/O Ethernet module with ROS. I'm using some example code, to ensure it works. I have compiled the code with gcc, so I know the code works. I compiled it from a terminal with this line:

> g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread main.cpp -Wall -O3 -omain_test -L/usr/local/lib -lmxio_x64

I get the main_test.out and it works.

So I created a catkin workspace and a new package by following the ROS tutorial. I add my code to the src folder, edits the CMakeList and the package.xml. Then when I try to run catkin_make -Wall (to get rid of a lot of warnings), I get the following message:

```
Base path: /home/johau/ros_ws
Source space: /home/johau/ros_ws/src
Build space: /home/johau/ros_ws/build
Devel space: /home/johau/ros_ws/devel
Install space: /home/johau/ros_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/johau/ros_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/johau/ros_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/johau/ros_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/johau/ros_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/johau/ros_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.9
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - master
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'master'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(master)
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/johau/ros_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -Wall -j8 -l8" in "/home/johau/ros_ws/build"
####
Linking CXX executable /home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main
CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xdd0): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
/usr/local/lib/libmxio_x64.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

I also got the "undefined reference to 'phread_create'" when I compiled with gcc, and solved that problem by calling -pthread before main.cpp.
So my problem now is, how can I do the same with CMake?
I have searched a lot and tried different solutions, but nothing have worked so far. I'm pretty green, when it comes to ROS and CMake, so I'm not sure what to add where, or if I have written something wrong somewhere in my CMakeLists.txt or package.xml.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and ROS Indigo.
If you need anymore info, let my know.

On before hand, thanks.

[EDIT 1]
I have now tried adding

> set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lpthread")

After project(master) in the CMakeLists.txt.
I also tried with:

> set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread")

and

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-pthread")
```

But it gave the same error message.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(master)

unset(MOXA_LIBRARY CACHE)

find_library(
   MOXA_LIBRARY
   NAMES mxio_x64
   PATHS /usr/local/lib
   PATH_SUFFIXES lib
   NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)

if(MOXA_LIBRARY STREQUAL "MOXA_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND")
    message(WARNING "Moxa Library not present !")
else()
    add_definitions(-DUSE_MOXA)
endif()

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
 find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################

catkin_package(
   CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
)

## Declare a cpp executable
 add_executable(main
     src/main.cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
 target_link_libraries(main
   ${MOXA_LIBRARY}
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
 )
```

My package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>master</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The master package</description>

  <maintainer email="johau@todo.todo">johau</maintainer>

  <license>BSD</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>


  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- You can specify that this package is a metapackage here: -->
    <!-- <metapackage/> -->

    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->

  </export>
</package>
```

[EDIT 2]
After request from @Lu-Niu did I run `catkin_make VERBOSE=1` (catkin_make should be the same as the make command, as far as I know, the catkin part is just because it's within ROS) and the output is in the box bellow. As far, as I can see, so is -pthread specified, while I think it should be -lpthread, when the directory isn't specified first (correct me, if I'm wrong). So what should I edit, to change the order of the command?

```
Base path: /home/johau/ros_ws
Source space: /home/johau/ros_ws/src
Build space: /home/johau/ros_ws/build
Devel space: /home/johau/ros_ws/devel
Install space: /home/johau/ros_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/johau/ros_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make VERBOSE=1 -j8 -l8" in "/home/johau/ros_ws/build"
####
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/johau/ros_ws/src -B/home/johau/ros_ws/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/johau/ros_ws/build/CMakeFiles /home/johau/ros_ws/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make -f master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
cd /home/johau/ros_ws/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/johau/ros_ws/src /home/johau/ros_ws/src/master /home/johau/ros_ws/build /home/johau/ros_ws/build/master /home/johau/ros_ws/build/master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make -f master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
Linking CXX executable /home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main
cd /home/johau/ros_ws/build/master && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/main.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -lpthread    CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o  -o /home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main  -L/usr/local/lib -rdynamic -lmxio_x64 /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so -lboost_signals -lboost_filesystem /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.so -llog4cxx -lboost_regex /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librostime.so -lboost_date_time /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libcpp_common.so -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread -lconsole_bridge -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib 
CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xdd0): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
/usr/local/lib/libmxio_x64.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make[1]: *** [master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

[EDIT 3]
Both of @fenix688 's suggestions are giving this output (with VERBOSE=1):

```
Base path: /home/johau/ros_ws
Source space: /home/johau/ros_ws/src
Build space: /home/johau/ros_ws/build
Devel space: /home/johau/ros_ws/devel
Install space: /home/johau/ros_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/johau/ros_ws/build"
####
#### Running command: "make VERBOSE=1 -j8 -l8" in "/home/johau/ros_ws/build"
####
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/johau/ros_ws/src -B/home/johau/ros_ws/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/johau/ros_ws/build/CMakeFiles /home/johau/ros_ws/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make -f master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
cd /home/johau/ros_ws/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/johau/ros_ws/src /home/johau/ros_ws/src/master /home/johau/ros_ws/build /home/johau/ros_ws/build/master /home/johau/ros_ws/build/master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make -f master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
Linking CXX executable /home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main
cd /home/johau/ros_ws/build/master && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/main.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o  -o /home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main  -L/usr/local/lib -rdynamic -lpthread -lboost_thread -lpthread -lmxio_x64 /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so -lboost_signals -lboost_filesystem /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.so -llog4cxx -lboost_regex /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librostime.so -lboost_date_time /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libcpp_common.so -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread -lconsole_bridge -lmxio_x64 /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so -lboost_signals -lboost_filesystem /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.so -llog4cxx -lboost_regex /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librostime.so -lboost_date_time /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libcpp_common.so -lboost_system -lconsole_bridge -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib 
CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xdd0): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
/usr/local/lib/libmxio_x64.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make[1]: *** [master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

While if I remove everything with pthread from the CMakeLists.txt do I get this VERBOSE=1 output, where -lpthread still is set.

```
Base path: /home/johau/ros_ws
Source space: /home/johau/ros_ws/src
Build space: /home/johau/ros_ws/build
Devel space: /home/johau/ros_ws/devel
Install space: /home/johau/ros_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/johau/ros_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make VERBOSE=1 -j8 -l8" in "/home/johau/ros_ws/build"
####
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/johau/ros_ws/src -B/home/johau/ros_ws/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/johau/ros_ws/build/CMakeFiles /home/johau/ros_ws/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make -f master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
cd /home/johau/ros_ws/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/johau/ros_ws/src /home/johau/ros_ws/src/master /home/johau/ros_ws/build /home/johau/ros_ws/build/master /home/johau/ros_ws/build/master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make -f master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
Linking CXX executable /home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main
cd /home/johau/ros_ws/build/master && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/main.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o  -o /home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main  -L/usr/local/lib -rdynamic -lmxio_x64 /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so -lboost_signals -lboost_filesystem /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.so -llog4cxx -lboost_regex /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librostime.so -lboost_date_time /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libcpp_common.so -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread -lconsole_bridge -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib 
CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xdd0): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
/usr/local/lib/libmxio_x64.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make[1]: *** [master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

[EDIT 4]
Tried with the CMakeLists.txt @fenix688 wrote and it gave the same error with this output:

```
Base path: /home/johau/ros_ws
Source space: /home/johau/ros_ws/src
Build space: /home/johau/ros_ws/build
Devel space: /home/johau/ros_ws/devel
Install space: /home/johau/ros_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/johau/ros_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make VERBOSE=1 -j8 -l8" in "/home/johau/ros_ws/build"
####
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/johau/ros_ws/src -B/home/johau/ros_ws/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/johau/ros_ws/build/CMakeFiles /home/johau/ros_ws/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make -f master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
cd /home/johau/ros_ws/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/johau/ros_ws/src /home/johau/ros_ws/src/master /home/johau/ros_ws/build /home/johau/ros_ws/build/master /home/johau/ros_ws/build/master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make -f master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
Linking CXX executable /home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main
cd /home/johau/ros_ws/build/master && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/main.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o  -o /home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main  -L/usr/local/lib -rdynamic -lpthread -lmxio_x64 /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so -lboost_signals -lboost_filesystem /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.so -llog4cxx -lboost_regex /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librostime.so -lboost_date_time /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libcpp_common.so -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread -lconsole_bridge -lboost_thread -lpthread -lconsole_bridge -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib 
CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xdd0): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
/usr/local/lib/libmxio_x64.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/johau/ros_ws/devel/lib/master/main] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make[1]: *** [master/CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/johau/ros_ws/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

Comment: one way to solve should be adding this line after `project(master)`: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lpthread")`.

Comment: I just tried that, but I got the same error. I also tried with the direct path to the pthread library, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we need to investigate on your issue. When you run make after cmake, could you run `make VERBOSE=1` so that we can see the actual command it execute and whether the pthread flag is specified correctly. you can also refer to this thread: [Using CMake with GNU Make: How can I see the exact commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670121/using-cmake-with-gnu-make-how-can-i-see-the-exact-commands)

Comment: I just runned the command and added the output to the end of my question, since this comment was not big enough for the output.

Comment: You have multiple pthread flag in your single command. Could you refer to this answer to correct that?http://stackoverflow.com/a/1665110/1646996

Comment: Yeah, I can see that I do have multiple pthread flags. I removed everything with pthread from the CMakeLists.txt. I still get the undefined reference error. With VERBOSE=1, do I get a long list of flags, but there is still one pthread flag left.
So where do I chance that. I have searched for how to change CMake flags and the order of them, but I got nothing. 
I guess, I need to set the pthread flag before the mxio_x64 flag, because the mxio library are using pthreads.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this complete **CMakeLists.txt** code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(master)

unset(MOXA_LIBRARY CACHE)

find_library(
   MOXA_LIBRARY
   NAMES mxio_x64
   PATHS /usr/local/lib
   PATH_SUFFIXES lib
   NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)

if(MOXA_LIBRARY STREQUAL "MOXA_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND")
    message(WARNING "Moxa Library not present !")
else()
    add_definitions(-DUSE_MOXA)
endif()

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################

catkin_package(
   CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
)

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(main src/main.cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries (main    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
                               ${MOXA_LIBRARY}
                               ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
                               ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

I hope it works!

Comment: I could set the pthread flag at, was I guess, was the right place. But it is also set later at the same time as some boost library flags, and I don't know how to change that, since those flags aren't set in the CMakeLists.txt.
Any idea where to change that?

Comment: I just tried that, but it just added the same flags over again, but in the right place (at least I hope, it is the right place). 
But thank you for taking your time trying to help :)

Comment: I added the complete example with some modifications. Please, tell me if it works :)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but I just tried with your example and got the same error again. But again, thanks for trying :)

I will try to look into some config files, and hope I will find something usefull there.