# Undefined Reference for Single File

Tags: c, linker, pthreads, undefined-reference

I saw from other posts on StackOverflow that the undefined reference error means that a definition is missing and that generally to fix it, files must be linked in compilation. But I am only compiling one file. I am getting this error for the functions `pthread_detach` and `pthread_create`.

```
/tmp/ccAET7bU.o: In function `sample_thread1':
foo.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'

/tmp/ccAET7bU.o: In function `main':
foo.c:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `pthread_create'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pid_t gettid(void)
{
    return syscall(__NR_gettid);
}

void *sample_thread1(void *x_void_ptr)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int counter;

    pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    if((fp = fopen("thread_data.txt", "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR : Thread cannot open data file.\n");
        return;
    }   
    counter = 1;
    while(1);
    {
        fprintf(fp, "INFO : Thread1 id %d output message %10d\n",
                gettid(), counter);
        fflush(fp);
        counter++;
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int counter;
    pthread_t sample_thread_t1;

    if(pthread_create(&sample_thread_t1, NULL, sample_thread1, NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    system("clear");

    counter = 1;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("INFO : Main Process Counter = %d\n", counter);
        counter++;
        sleep(1);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to pass -lpthread to gcc to tell it to link against the pthread library. undefined reference just means the linker can't find the functions you called in the code

Comment: Which OS are you running for this one?

Comment: For Linux pease read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1662909/694576

Comment: Btw: I feel typos in titles are embarrassing ...

Answer (score 2):

You have to link this with a `pthread` library using `-lpthread` or `-pthread` options of GCC or clang.

Examples:

```
gcc your_file.c -o program -lpthread
# or gcc your_file.c -o program -pthread
# the same for clang
```

Comment: `-lpthread` and `-pthread` are not necessarily the same. One should consult the implementations documentation for which one has to be used. For Linux for example the man-page (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) expliciltly states to use `-pthread`!

Comment: @alk, three or more times I faced a problem with `-lpthread` on a jailbroken iPhone and used `-pthread` which worked perfectly well. That's why I suggested two options top try.

Comment: `-pthread` would always imply linking the PThreads library, which is all that `-lpthread` does, as opposed to `-pthread` which might do much more, like setting compile time "switches".