# C++ code compiles on mac but not on linux

Tags: c++, linux

My code works perfectly on my mac but does not compile on linux.  I get the compile error

```
/tmp/ccWcFSEW.o: In function `main':
DroneMap.cpp:(.text.startup+0x22d): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
DroneMap.cpp:(.text.startup+0x262): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone have any idea what this error message means or why i am getting it because i cant figure it out.

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -O3

all: DroneMap

clean:
    rm -rf DroneMap
```

Comment: Those are linker errors.  It can't resolve calls to the pthread library.  Check to make sure that the linker can find the pthread library (usually via the -L option).

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1665110/4440992).

Comment: Your code wants to link the `pthreads` library. Ensure you have `-pthread` specified when compiling and linking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the pthread library in your compilation command, i dont know how you compile it in MAC, but the correct compile command for linux will be like that.

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-pthread -Wall -O3

all: DroneMap

clean:
    rm -rf DroneMap
```

Comment: im sorry i dont know much about make files, how would i change mine

CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -O3

all: DroneMap

clean:
 rm -rf DroneMap

Comment: Add your make file in your article so we can help you

Comment: Look at my modification in my answer