# Undefined reference to pthread_create pthread_join' in Linux

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
volatile int Licznik;

void * thread1 (void * v1){
    while(1) Licznik++;
}

void * thread2 (void * v1){
    while(1) printf("%d ", Licznik);
}

int main(){
    pthread_t w1, w2;
    pthread_create(&w1, NULL, thread1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&w2, NULL, thread2, NULL);
    sleep(5);
    pthread_join(w1, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
/tmp/ccfGEzAp.o: In function `main':
main1.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
main1.c:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
main1.c:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `pthread_jo
```

Comment: Tried compiling with `-pthread`?

Comment: Use `-lpthread` flag with gcc during compilation

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling

Comment: may be you can compile with -lpthread

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to pthread\_create in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662909/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create-in-linux)