# undefined reference to `pthread_create' -pthread not working

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm creating new threads in a function, and I've included pthread.h. But it's not working, I keep receiving the following error upon compiling:

> undefined reference to `pthread_create'

The flags I'm using to compile are the following:

> CFLAGS=-std=gnu99 -pthread -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror
>   -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wunused -Wold-style-definition -Wundef -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wunreachable-code

The compiler is gcc

Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=gnu99 -pthread -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wunused -Wold-style-definition -Wundef -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wunreachable-code

all: finder

finder: stack.o list.o finder.o
    $(CC) -o mfind stack.o list.o mfind.o

stack.o: stack.c stack.h
    $(CC) -c stack.c $(CFLAGS)

list.o: list.c list.h
    $(CC) -c list.c $(CFLAGS)

finder.o: finder.c finder.h
    $(CC) -c finder.c $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o finder
```

Comment: `CFLAGS` is normally the wrong variable to put linked libraries into, many build systems put the `CFLAGS` on the command line *before* the files to be linked. Your build system might offer a `LIBS` variable where you can put `-pthread`. Not enough information to tell for sure.

Comment: And what *exact* command are you running when you get this error?

Comment: minimal code available?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I use a makefile, therefore CFLAGS to just define the flags I'm using.

Comment: I'm merely just t rying to compile my program with a makefile. I'm only creating new threads. @ChrisTurner

Comment: @CSPei This is what I'm calling to create new threads: pthread_create(&newT->tid, NULL, beginSearch, (void *)newT);

Comment: @Cows42 yes, but that doesn't answer my question does it

Comment: @Cows42 then show the (relevant parts of the) Makefile. I bet there's something like `gcc -o$@ $(CFLAGS) $<` for linking. `-pthread` must appear **after** the input files.

Comment: Makefile or no, we need to see the exact compile command being run or it's rather difficult to debug.  I would guess the linking stage is failing for not being passed the -lpthread flag, but we'd need the actual failing compile command to be sure.

Comment: Edit your question and post the complete Makefile

Comment: check the sample code [here] (https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) which can be compiled by 'gcc -pthread a.c'

Comment: Alright, I've edited main post with the makefile @FelixPalmen

Comment: Where in `$(CC) -o mfind stack.o list.o mfind.o` is `-pthread` or a variable that contains `-pthread`?

Comment: @ChrisTurner ahhhhh... didn't see that $(CFLAGS) was missing on that row.. :/ Thanks!

Comment: @Cows42 no, you don't put `$(CFLAGS)` there. See my answer... `$(CFLAGS)` is by convention used for flags needed during *compilation*, `$(LDFLAGS)` for those used during linking (you don't need any here) and `$(LIBS)` for libraries that get linked.

Comment: @FelixPalmen oh ok I understand, thanks :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen there's no reason not to include `$(CFLAGS)` as well

Comment: @ChrisTurner it serves no purpose and you get better readable output without heaps of redundant flags. Sooner or later, you *will* have the situation that you need different flags for different stages.

Comment: almost a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662909/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create-in-linux?rq=1

Comment: Isn't it that way CFLAGS is only for those whose builds the package but not for package maintainer (means for people who generate autotools output files and distribute them along with package in source-code form)? For package maintainer AM_CFLAGS and target-specific CFLAGS seem to be intended. Package maintainer builds package for own testing. Real building takes place on user station.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-pthread` is needed at the linking stage, not when compiling the individual translation units. A typical approach would look like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=gnu99 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wunused -Wold-style-definition -Wundef -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wunreachable-code
LIBS=-pthread

all: finder

finder: stack.o list.o finder.o
    $(CC) -o mfind stack.o list.o mfind.o $(LIBS)

stack.o: stack.c stack.h
    $(CC) -c stack.c $(CFLAGS)

list.o: list.c list.h
    $(CC) -c list.c $(CFLAGS)

finder.o: finder.c finder.h
    $(CC) -c finder.c $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o finder
```