# Multi-threaded Sudoku Solver

Tags: c, multithreading, solver, sudoku

Well there is a code about my question which i found it helpful, but when i try to compile it there are some errors about the pointers.

I've tried a lot, but Pointers were always my issue.

```
typedef struct 
{
    // The starting row.
    int row;
    // The starting column.
    int col;
    // The pointer to the board.
    int (* board)[9];
} parameters;

// Prototype for the walk_rows function.
void * walk_rows(void * params);

// Prototype for the walk_cols function.
void * walk_cols(void * params);

// Prototype for 3x3 square function.
void * check_square(void * params);

/***************
 * ENTRY POINT
 **************/
int main(void) 
{
    // ====== Create the board =======
    int board[9][9] = {  
            {6, 2, 4, 5, 3, 9, 1, 8, 7},
            {5, 1, 9, 7, 2, 8, 6, 3, 4},
            {8, 3, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 9, 5},
            {1, 4, 3, 8, 6, 5, 7, 2, 9},
            {9, 5, 8, 2, 4, 7, 3, 6, 1},
            {7, 6, 2, 3, 9, 1, 4, 5, 8},
            {3, 7, 1, 9, 5, 6, 8, 4, 2},
            {4, 9, 6, 1, 8, 2, 5, 7, 3},
            {2, 8, 5, 4, 7, 3, 9, 1, 6}
        };

    // ====== Create the parameter for the columns and rows check =======
    parameters * param0 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    param0->row = 0;
    param0->col = 0;
    param0->board = board;

    // ====== Create the parameters for the 3x3 threads ======

    // First 3x3
    parameters * param1 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    param1->row = 0;
    param1->col = 0;
    param1->board = board;

    // Second 3x3
    parameters * param2 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    param2->row = 0;
    param2->col = 3;
    param2->board = board;

    // Third 3x3
    parameters * param3 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    param3->row = 0;
    param3->col = 6;
    param3->board = board;

    // Fourth 3x3
    parameters * param4 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    param4->row = 3;
    param4->col = 0;
    param4->board = board;

    // Fifth 3x3
    parameters * param5 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    param5->row = 3;
    param5->col = 3;
    param5->board = board;

    // Sixth 3x3
    parameters * param6 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    param6->row = 3;
    param6->col = 6;
    param6->board = board;

    // Seventh 3x3
    parameters * param7 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    param7->row = 6;
    param7->col = 0;
    param7->board = board;

    // Eighth 3x3
    parameters * param8 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    param8->row = 6;
    param8->col = 3;
    param8->board = board;

    // Ninth 3x3
    parameters * param9 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    param9->row = 6;
    param9->col = 6;
    param9->board = board;

    // ====== Create the threads ======
    pthread_t thread_rows, thread_cols, thread1, thread2, thread3, thread4, thread5, thread6, thread7, thread8, thread9;

    // ====== Create the return values for the threads ======
    void * all_rows;
    void * all_cols;
    void * square1;
    void * square2;
    void * square3;
    void * square4;
    void * square5;
    void * square6;
    void * square7;
    void * square8;
    void * square9;

    // ====== Initialize the threads ======
    pthread_create(&thread_rows, NULL, walk_rows, (void *) param0);
    pthread_create(&thread_cols, NULL, walk_cols, (void *) param0);
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, check_square, (void *) param1);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, check_square, (void *) param2);
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, check_square, (void *) param3);
    pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, check_square, (void *) param4);
    pthread_create(&thread5, NULL, check_square, (void *) param5);
    pthread_create(&thread6, NULL, check_square, (void *) param6);
    pthread_create(&thread7, NULL, check_square, (void *) param7);
    pthread_create(&thread8, NULL, check_square, (void *) param8);
    pthread_create(&thread9, NULL, check_square, (void *) param9);

    // ======= Wait for all threads to finish their tasks =======
    pthread_join(thread_rows, &all_rows);
    pthread_join(thread_cols, &all_cols);
    pthread_join(thread1, &square1);
    pthread_join(thread2, &square2);
    pthread_join(thread3, &square3);
    pthread_join(thread4, &square4);
    pthread_join(thread5, &square5);
    pthread_join(thread6, &square6);
    pthread_join(thread7, &square7);
    pthread_join(thread8, &square8);
    pthread_join(thread9, &square9);

    // ====== Check whether the Sudoku Puzzle was solved ======
    if (    (int) all_rows == 1 &&
            (int) all_cols == 1 &&
            (int) square1 == 1 &&
            (int) square2 == 1 &&
            (int) square3 == 1 &&
            (int) square4 == 1 &&
            (int) square5 == 1 &&
            (int) square6 == 1 &&
            (int) square7 == 1 &&
            (int) square8 == 1 &&
            (int) square9 == 1 ) {
        printf("The Sudoku Puzzle is solved!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("The Sudoku Puzzle is NOT solved.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

/**
 * Checks each row if it contains all digits 1-9.
 * @param   void *      The parameters (pointer).
 * @return  void *      1 if all rows contain all digits from 1-9, 0 otherwise.
 */
void * walk_rows(void * params) {
    parameters * data = (parameters *) params;
    int startRow = data->row;
    int startCol = data->col;
    for (int i = startRow; i < 9; ++i) {
        int row[10] = {0};
        for (int j = startCol; j < 9; ++j) {
            int val = data->board[i][j];
            if (row[val] != 0) {
                return (void *) 0;
            }
            else{
                row[val] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return (void *) 1;
}

/**
 * Checks each column if it contains all digits 1-9.
 * @param   void *      The parameters (pointer).
 * @return  void *      1 if all rows contain all digits from 1-9, 0 otherwise.
 */
void * walk_cols(void * params) {
    parameters * data = (parameters *) params;
    int startRow = data->row;
    int startCol = data->col;
    for (int i = startCol; i < 9; ++i) {
        int col[10] = {0};
        for (int j = startRow; j < 9; ++j) {
            int val = data->board[j][i];
            if (col[val] != 0) {
                return (void *) 0;
            }
            else{
                col[val] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return (void *) 1;
}

/**
 * Checks if a square of size 3x3 contains all numbers from 1-9.
 * @param   void *      The parameters (pointer).
 * @return  void *      1 if all rows contain all digits from 1-9, 0 otherwise.
 */
void * check_square(void * params) {
    parameters * data = (parameters *) params;
    int startRow = data->row;
    int startCol = data->col;
    int saved[10] = {0};
    for (int i = startRow; i < startRow + 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = startCol; j < startCol + 3; ++j) {
            int val = data->board[i][j];
            if (saved[val] != 0) {
                return (void *) 0;
            }
            else{
                saved[val] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return (void *) 1;
}
```

I don't get it, is there a problem about differences between the size of integers and pointers? 
and what reference should i define for `pthread_create'?

```
$gcc -o main *.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:174:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
     if (    (int) all_rows == 1 &&
             ^
main.c:175:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
             (int) all_cols == 1 &&
             ^
main.c:176:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
             (int) square1 == 1 &&
             ^
main.c:177:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
             (int) square2 == 1 &&
             ^
main.c:178:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
             (int) square3 == 1 &&
             ^
main.c:179:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
             (int) square4 == 1 &&
             ^
main.c:180:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
             (int) square5 == 1 &&
             ^
main.c:181:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
             (int) square6 == 1 &&
             ^
main.c:182:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
             (int) square7 == 1 &&
             ^
main.c:183:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
             (int) square8 == 1 &&
             ^
main.c:184:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
             (int) square9 == 1 ) {
             ^
/tmp/ccz3xnwE.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x247): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
main.c:(.text+0x267): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
main.c:(.text+0x287): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
main.c:(.text+0x2a7): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
main.c:(.text+0x2c7): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/tmp/ccz3xnwE.o:main.c:(.text+0x2e7): more undefined references to `pthread_create' follow
/tmp/ccz3xnwE.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x3a0): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
main.c:(.text+0x3b9): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
main.c:(.text+0x3d2): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
main.c:(.text+0x3eb): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
```

Comment: This code *urgently* needs arrays. Variables of the form `square1`..`squareN` is not really sustainable, you're going to have errors creep undetected. You also need to break this up into simpler functions, each of which has a singular, well-defined responsibility. There's rampant duplication here which makes reviewing the code unnecessarily challenging.

Comment: The big question here is why you're using `void*` at all when the type of the pointer is well-defined. Don't do this. Let the threads populate some structure in memory and read that back after. Don't try and shovel data back over the `join`.

Comment: Your platform probably requires you to pass the `-pthread` flag to the compiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to pthread\_create in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662909/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create-in-linux)

Comment: Unless this is an exercise to learn the basics of threads, I suspect a normal single process would be quite a bit more efficient for checking the 9-cells in each of the 9-rows of the game. Consider [5 Big Fat Reasons Why Mutexes Suck Big Time](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload149.pdf) (2nd Article on multi-threading in general)

Answer (score 0):

Your casting a pointer into an int. 
Can you cast it (int*) instead?

Comment: I did, new errors. main.c:175:29: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
             (int*) all_cols == 1 &&
                             ^~

Comment: Sorry, had to go eat.
Did you fix it?
Can you show that full line of code? I can't see what your trying to compare.

Comment: Totally fine. The line i wrote was a line of error which i'mma write in other comment, but for now i replaced the int to int* as you said. And that was the error says comparison between pointer and integer.

Comment: if (    (int) all_rows == 1 &&
            (int) all_cols == 1 &&
            (int) square1 == 1 &&
            (int) square2 == 1 &&
            (int) square3 == 1 &&
            (int) square4 == 1 &&
            (int) square5 == 1 &&
            (int) square6 == 1 &&
            (int) square7 == 1 &&
            (int) square8 == 1 &&
            (int) square9 == 1 ) {

Comment: if (    (int*) all_rows == 1 &&
            (int*) all_cols == 1 &&
            (int*) square1 == 1 &&
            (int*) square2 == 1 &&
            (int*) square3 == 1 &&
            (int*) square4 == 1 &&
            (int*) square5 == 1 &&
            (int*) square6 == 1 &&
            (int*) square7 == 1 &&
            (int*) square8 == 1 &&
            (int*) square9 == 1 ) {

Comment: It may be your syntax.

if ( (int*)all_rows == 1) && (int*)all_cols == 1) && etc...

Answer (score 0):

First, You likely need to link with -lpthread. if you are on a unix-like OS.

Next, they aren't errors, they are warnings.   You are forced into these types by the pthreads spec -- threads return pointers -- which you are using as values.   The compiler needs  cascaded casts to shut up:

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
if ((int)(intptr_t)all_rows == 1)
...
```

although you could get away with:

```
if ((intptr_t)all_rows == 1)
```

This is mainly due to widespread abuse of casts (every time you want to cast something, giver yourself a little pinch).   At some point, I predict you will require 5 cascaded casts to convince the compiler you do know what you are doing :)