# How to link/include c++ libraries correctly

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I tried to compile program with https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib "one-header" library. I wrote

```cpp
#include "httplib.h"
/* example code from main github page */
```

and when i tried to compile program

```sh
g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cc
```

i got this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccYMj4l8.o: in function `std::thread::thread<httplib::ThreadPool::worker, , void>(httplib::ThreadPool::worker&&)':
test.cc:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IN7httplib10ThreadPool6workerEJEvEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IN7httplib10ThreadPool6workerEJEvEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x2f): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What can i do?
And how to link libraries that have `include` and `src` directories, e.g. libcurl

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to pthread\_create in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662909/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create-in-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's gcc's known particular feature, its `std::thread` implementation is built upon pthreads so it requires specifying `-pthread` to correctly link programs with threads.